# error when run flutter app on IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

I create an application using flutter but I am facing an issue when trying to run it IOS simulator
I am getting the following error

```
Error (Xcode): In /Users/user214711/Desktop/flutter_apps/guide/ios/Pods/Sodium/Sodium/libsodium/libsodium-ios.a(libsodium_la-aead_xchacha20poly1305.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for
architecture arm64


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

I tried many solution on the internet but unfortunately all solutions was related for. native IOS apps not flutter apps
here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Basically, you have to exclude arm64 for the simulator architecture, both from your project and the Pod project,

Answer (score 1):

Open your iOS workspace in Xcode and make sure under Debug you are running only the active architecture. Follow these steps:[image]